# How to get mouse position in the same place with different resolutions

Tags: java, coordinates, screen-resolution, java-2d, mouselistener

I developed a Monopoly Clone game (Bolivian monopoly) for the university.
I put the monopoly board into Jpanel and try to get the mouse position in the exactly coordinate using e.getX() into the mouse listener event. the problem is that my game supports a loot of resolution 800x600, 1024x768, 1680x1050 .... How can i get the same location click when i chance the screen resolution??
[image]

Comment: I want to click on a property card and open a new window with information about the card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way would be to not work with pixel coordinates but with percent coordinates.

on the screenshot, your board has a top offset and a left offset, as well as a width and a height.

for the current mouse x position, subtract the left offset and divide by the width of the game-board. the x value you will get will be:

less than 0: mouse is left of the board
between 0 and 1: relative position on the board (0 is totally on the left, 1 is totally on the right) 
greater than one: mouse position is right of the board.

same applies for the y position.

If you then do all you clipping calculations based on these relative values, everything should work dependency independent.

Comment: I want to click on a property card and open a new window with information about the card –

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should place every picture on different `JPanel`. You can use `JLabel` to add picture. This way you can add listeners to each picture. It will support any screen resoultion as it follows `Layout Manager`. Also, It will help you to organize code logically.

Comment: not sure if this is the best approach. say you want to have the movement of the game figures anmiated - this will be very painful if you have split your rendering area. over several jpanels.

also configuring a layout manager in such a way will be quite some effort aswell.